# Cannot create bundled product in magento 1.9 - tabs are empty/blank

Tags: magento, nginx, php

I cannot create bundled products in my recently upgrade (1.5 -> 1.9) magento.

When I go to created a bundled product, the "Product Information" tabs are all empty/blank like this:

[image]

I cannot see any errors in **system.log** or **exception.log**, I even checked for errors in JS Console in chrome as well as nginx/php-fpm logs (there were nothing in there).

Any idea why this is? How can I fix this?

Comment: Between 1.5 and 1.9 a lot of changes have been done. If you have database dump from before the upgrade I would suggest to download versions 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 and do upgrades step by step. If not try to disable all 3rd part modules. If this fixes the issue enable them one by one and check which one causes the problem.

Comment: could be a lot of things. have a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429 for a good set of debugging guidlines

Comment: @Zefiryn - that's exactly how I upgraded the magento. I did not need any of the modules, so what I did was, backed up my database and then downloaded a fresh copy of 1.6 and pointed to that db and the mage upgraded. I repeated this process against the same database until I was at 1.9. the magento was incrementally updated.

Comment: @Latheesan then try to do that again and check after each update if the problem occurs. One more thing about js errors. In some packages magento came with disabled console in all browser except Firefox. Check file in js/varien/js.js for string `"console" in window`

Answer (score 3):

This happens when Mage_Bundle is disabled. Make sure its enabled.